# Counter inside a loop

Tags: python

I've got the following section of my code. I'm trying to create a dataframe but the "load" counter does not update properly and is always equal to zero instead of 68.

```py
dssCircuit.SetActiveClass('Load') 
num_carichi=dssLoads.Count  
# delta_wye=dssLoads.IsDelta
wye=0 
load=0
if num_carichi==0:
    print('Non ci sono carichi')
else:
    for i in dssLoads.Name:
        dssCircuit.SetActiveElement(i)
        CAZZOMERDA=dssLoads.IsDelta
        if  CAZZOMERDA is True:             
            dfload=pd.DataFrame(list(zip(nomi_load, bus_load, tensione_load, correnti_load, phases_load, pot_load)),
                                    columns=['Nome', 'Bus', 'kV', 'Correnti', 'n° fasi', 'Potenza'])
            dfload[['A kV Mag', 'A kV phase', 'B kV Mag', 'B kV phase', 'C kV Mag', 'C kV phase']] = pd.DataFrame(dfload['kV'].tolist())
            dfload[['A kW', 'A kVAR', 'B kW', 'B kVAR', 'C kW', 'C kVAR']] = pd.DataFrame(dfload['Potenza'].tolist())
            dfload=dfload.drop(columns=['kV', 'Potenza'])
        elif CAZZOMERDA is False:
             dfload=pd.DataFrame(list(zip(nomi_load, bus_load, tensione_load, correnti_load, phases_load, pot_load )),
                                          columns = ['Nome', 'Bus', 'kV', 'Correnti', 'n° fasi', 'Potenze'])
             dfload[['A kV Mag', 'A kV phase', 'B kV Mag', 'B kV phase', 'C kV Mag', 'C kV phase', 'N kV Mag', 'N kV phase']] = pd.DataFrame(dfload['kV'].tolist())
             dfload[['A kW', 'A kVAR', 'B kW', 'B kVAR', 'C kW', 'C kVAR', 'N kW', 'N kVAR']] = pd.DataFrame(dfload['Potenze'].tolist())
             dfload=dfload.drop(columns=['kV', 'Potenze'])
    
    for pappa in dssLoads.AllNames:
        x = load
        print('0')
        dssCircuit.SetActiveElement(pappa)
        if dssElem.NumPhases==1:
            print('1')
            if  pappa.endswith('a'):
                df_load.loc[j, 'N Corr Mag'] = df_load.loc[x, 'B Corr Mag']
                df_load.loc[j, 'N Corr phase'] = df_load.loc[x, 'B Corr phase']
                df_load.loc[j, 'B Corr Mag'] = 0
                df_load.loc[j, 'B Corr phase'] = 0
                df_load.loc[j, 'N kW'] = df_load.loc[x, 'B kW']
                df_load.loc[j, 'N kVAR'] = df_load.loc[x, 'B kVAR']
                df_load.loc[j, 'B kW'] = 0
                df_load.loc[j, 'B kVAR'] = 0
            elif pappa.endswith('b'):
                  df_load.loc[j, 'N Corr Mag'] = df_load.loc[x, 'B Corr Mag']
                  df_load.loc[j, 'N Corr phase'] = df_load.loc[x, 'B Corr phase']
                  df_load.loc[j, 'B kV Mag'] = df_load.loc[x, 'A kV Mag']
                  df_load.loc[j, 'B kV phase'] = df_load.loc[x, 'A kV phase'] 
                  df_load.loc[j, 'B Corr Mag'] = df_load.loc[x, 'A Corr Mag']
                  df_load.loc[j, 'B Corr phase'] = df_load.loc[x, 'A Corr phase']
                  df_load.loc[j, 'A Corr Mag'] = 0
                  df_load.loc[j, 'A Corr phase'] = 0
                  df_load.loc[j, 'B kW'] = df_load.loc[x, 'A kW']
                  df_load.loc[j, 'B kVAR'] = df_load.loc[x, 'A kVAR']
                  df_load.loc[j, 'A kW'] = 0
                  df_load.loc[j, 'A kVAR'] = 0
            elif  pappa.endswith('c'):
                  df_load.loc[j, 'C kV Mag'] = df_load.loc[x, 'A kV Mag']
                  df_load.loc[j, 'C kV phase'] = df_load.loc[x, 'A kV phase']
                  df_load.loc[j, 'A kV Mag'] = 0
                  df_load.loc[j, 'A kV Mag phase'] = 0
                  df_load.loc[j, 'N Corr Mag'] = df_load.loc[x, 'B Corr Mag']
                  df_load.loc[j, 'B Corr Mag'] = 0
                  df_load.loc[j, 'N Corr phase'] = df_load.loc[x, 'B Corr phase']
                 ` df_load.loc[j, 'B Corr phase'] = 0
                  df_load.loc[j, 'C Corr Mag'] = df_load.loc[x, 'A Corr Mag']
                  df_load.loc[j, 'C Corr phase'] = df_load.loc[x, 'A Corr phase']
                  df_load.loc[j, 'A Corr Mag'] = 0
                  df_load.loc[j, 'A Corr phase'] = 0  
        load+=1
```

I want the loop to iterate over every load in the list, but it remains equal to zero.

Comment: @blackraven: Why would that make a difference?

Comment: If the program never executes the `print('0')`, then the `load+=1` line will also never execute. What is `dssLoads.AllNames`?

Comment: print('0') get printed but not 68 times as I want. 
dssLoads.AllNames is a OpenDSS function that make a list of names

Comment: Can you do `load = len(dssLoads.AllNames)` instead of making `load` count each one?

Comment: Can you do `load = load + 1`? (yes, I know it is silly, but does it work?)